# Pre launch report of Google Play Console shows too long cold start time

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, prelaunch

Pre launch report of Google Play Console shows too long cold start time, but does not give any details about it. Report shows only test devices without issues but not test devices with issues. It does not give which devices has higher cold start time or any log related it.

[image]

[image]

I can see all devices used in tests via Stability section. I think last two Google Pixel 2(virtual) have higher cold start time. Am I wrong?

[image]

I tried to robo test on Firebase Test Lab. I did not run tests on Google Pixel 2(virtual) because system skipped this device, but I finished test without any issue on Pixel 2(Arm).

I could run the application on Pixel 2 (x86_64 and SDK 32 emulator) through windows Pc. I didn't take abnormal cold start time.

Maybe I take a kind of false positive result on pre launch report.

Is there anyone who experience it? Do you have any idea or suggestion about that problem?

Comment: Same situation here: 2 devices marked as slow on cold boot, yet no details provided.